Where am I wrong in this variance calculation?
It is said that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\operatorname{Var}[X+Y]=\operatorname{Var}[X]+\operatorname{Var}[Y]$.
Given that $$Var[X]=E[X^{2}]-E^{2}[X]$$ then by substitution we arrive at $$Var[X+Y]=E[X^{2}]+2E[XY]+E[Y^{2}]-E^{2}[X]-E^{2}[Y]$$ if the random variables are independent then its clear that $$Var\left[X+Y\right]=Var\left[X\right]+Var\left[Y\right]+2E\left[X\right]E\left[Y\right]$$
This conclution is seemingly due to some wrong variable handling through these operations, but I am struggling to spot that out.

$E^2[X+Y]=(E[X]+E[Y])^2$ is not equal to $E^2[X]+E^2[Y]$.

How did you arrive at $E^2[X]$ being the same thing after substitution as $E^2[X]+E^2[Y]$?  Perhaps this is a fault of your choice of notation.  Recall that this is $(E[X])^2$.  After substitution this is $(E[X]+E[Y])^2$... and you should know that $(a+b)^2$ is not the same thing as $a^2+b^2$

Freshman's Dream.

$$E^2(X+Y) = (E(X+Y))^2 = (E(X)+E(Y))^2 = E^2(X) + 2E(XY) + E^2(Y)$$
The term with the 2 will cancel out and what remains is the variances you need.
